# What is "var _gaq = _gaq || []; " for?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The Async Tracking code in Google Analytics looks like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']); 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 

(function() { 
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
})();
```

About The first line:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

I think it ensures that if `_gaq` is already defined we should use it otherwise we should an array.

Can anybody explain what this is for?

Also, does it matter if `_gaq` gets renamed? In other words, does Google Analytics rely on a global object named `_gaq`?

Comment: It's also worth noting that, unless you’re actually using two snippets in the same page (and using bad code — there are much better ways to implement multiple trackers than to simply paste the snippet twice with different account IDs), you can safely replace this line with `var _gaq = []`. Some more possible micro-optimizations for the asynchronous Google Analytics snippet can be found here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it ensures that `_gaq` is defined, so that `_gaq.push()` never fails.

I would not mess with the name of the variables in GA's code... do you have any reason to? Does it conflict with any of your variables? (Then I would change mine...)

Comment: it would still fail if _gaq was declared before but wasn't an array but a number or string  :)

Comment: I don't have issue per se with '_gaq' but I have found nowhere in the google analytics documentation a warning about having a variable called _gaq.

Comment: That would be like an open invitation to hackers, like the robots.txt. You could interpret "please don't use xxx" as "our code is vulnerable when you use xxx". :-)

Comment: Well, if Google did issue a warning about using the _gaq variable, wouldn't you be tempted to experiment with it?

Just like the robots.txt: If you could read it, and it contained the line `Disallow: /admin/`, wouldn't you try adding '/admin/' to the URL to see what it did?

Comment: There is no documentation that says you shouldn't have a variable named _gaq, but if you want to use GA (including the non-async version), you should avoid using that namespace.

Comment: Just came across an issue - when assigning tracker events in jQuery - this line is not stable; _gaq is undefined and it seems that something is breaking the connection to original global array. This prevents the code from sending the beacon to GA.

Comment: Well, of course there is a reason to initialize _gaq, but there is also a reason to use specifically an array and its push method. I hope my answer will help to understand how well it fits with async loading. (This answer, although interesting, seemed too incomplete to me.)

Answer (score 25):

This line is there to allow multiple GA snippets in the same page. It ensures that the second snippet doesn't overwrite a _gaq defined by the first.

GA asynchronous tracking works by first defining _gaq as an array. This array acts like a queue, which allows you to push (append) configuration and tracking "commands" (like _trackPageview) onto the end of the queue. Your commands are stored in this array until ga.js fully downloads.

When ga.js is ready, it executes all the commands in the _gaq array and replaces _gaq with an object. This object also has a push method, but instead of queueing up commands, it executes them immediately, because ga.js is available to process them.

This mechanism allows you to make configuration and tracking commands without knowing if the browser has finished downloading ga.js. This is needed because the async snippet downloads ga.js without blocking other code on the page from running. Things would get hairy if that other code (your configuration commands) needed to know the state of ga.js being downloaded.

All of this absolutely **does** depend on the use of the name _gaq. You shouldn't try to name it if you want asynchronous tracking to work.

Answer (score 13):

Using `||` in assignment is a common programming trick which takes advantage of the evaluation direction of the operator, which is left to right. That means that it evaluates the left side first. Then, and **only if that is false** (or a false equivalent), does it evaluate the right side.

You can also take advantage of the `||` or `&&` operators in a simple if statement, so that

```
if (a > 5) {
  do_a();
}

if (!some_boolean) {
  do_b();
}
```

become

```
a > 5 && do_a();
some_boolean || do_b(); // Note that the negation operator `!` is gone!
```

which are both way nicer to look at.

The reason languages allow this, is because it is a waste of time evaluating the right side if the left side will make the entire line fail anyways. So it just ignores it unless it's needed.

Comment: I like the if statement more in your example, more human readable.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to answer late, but I read the accepted answer and I think that it misses the most important thing. So I'll try to explain what I understood :

First, it has been explained but the answer needs to be complete so I explain it too, the code begin with:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

It ensures that _gaq is defined. If it is not defined, it is initialized to an empty array.

Think it like the equivalent:

```
var _gaq;
/* ... */
if(!_gaq)
  _gaq = [];
```

The javascript value `undefined` is "falsish"/"falsy", ie it evaluates to false when converted to a boolean, so _gaq is initialized with `[]`  in this case.

What's important to note is that :

- if _gaq contains an array at this stage, _gaq is "trueish", so it will keep it's value (and not be emptied)
- if _gaq contains another type of object at this stage, _gaq can also keep its value

Well, I re-explained, as well as I can, something already explained. Most people experienced with javascript had already understood it. **However, the interesting part is not only the start!**

```
_gaq.push(['command', 'argument']); // is very interesting too
```

If _gaq is an array, you will all guess that the item `['command', 'argument']` is appended to the array. Google analytics store this in its queue for further processing. The array _gaq is used as a queue.

But the really interesting part is that`_gaq.push(/*...*/)` can be done without having an array named _gaq. It is just a method call, and non arrays can also have a "`push`" method.

It "opens new possibilities". Here is a summary of one:

- As long as the external javascript file is not asynchronously loaded, _gaq is an array used as a queue.
- The external ga.js then process the queue.
- ga.js then replaces _gaq by an object which provides a push method.
- Once _gaq is replaced by an object, the `_gaq.push(/*...*/)` commands don't need to be deferred anymore, they can be executed.

For those who missed the asynchronous script loading part, it is:

```
(function() { 
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
})();
```

Using temporarily an array as a queue and the push method is great code. It is a very interesting way to cope with the fact that when `_gaq.push(/*...*/)` is executed, we don't always now if the dependency has been asynchronously loaded yet or not.

Another related interesting way of managing this kind of problems is the [new Google Analytics "isogram" snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716542/google-analytics-code-explanation): `ga(/*...*/)` looks even more intuitive for calls that `_gaq.push(/*...*/)`, but it still copes with the joys related to loading dependencies in an asynchronous way.

> Can anybody explain what this is for?

I hope my answer above has done it. What I wanted to share here is that the first line is done in a particular way to fit with the whole thing: initialization that never harms if done twice, smart use of push method...

> does Google Analytics rely on a global object named _gaq?

Yes it does, when using this ga.js snippet.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

i will add more detail

_gaq is simply a javascript array, as first defined. you add events to it, such as event tracking callbacks

when the ga.js script is loaded, however, google takes this array and turns it into an object, that ga uses.

this is why you push functions into the _gaq array, then call the ga.js script after you;re done constructing the array.

gaq is google analytics queue. it's a stack for GA methods, like event tracking, page attribution, etc. you use the push() method to put GA stuff on there. reduces event interference, everyone should do this, or at least learn the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does exactly what you think it does :)
It is a shorthand for

```
if(!_gaq){ var _gaq = [] }
```

Comment: What is the _gaq variable itself for, or the assigment of an empty array to this variable? It looks like the tracking script uses _gaq global variable to hold some data before sending them to the server. Compressed source is a bit hard to follow, but there is var ba="_gaq" on the first line, and var i = window[ba]; (which returns the _gaq global variable) on the last line. Making _gaq an array if it is not defined just makes it possoble to use .push() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

This means that if _gaq is already defined it use that else it declares an empty array. With push you can override settings. If the _gaq object wasnt defined the 2 "lines" after that would result in an error.

Yes the _gaq object is expect in the script which you include in the code there (ga.js).