# what does this mean: var _gaq = _gaq || [];

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In Javascript, what does it mean when there is a logical operator in a variable declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable-d)
>   [what’s the javascript “var _gaq = _gaq || []; ” for ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538252/whats-the-javascript-var-gaq-gaq-for)

what does this javascript syntax mean?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

Comment: duplicate of: [what’s the javascript `var _gaq = _gaq || \[\];` for ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538252/whats-the-javascript-var-gaq-gaq-for) and see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable-declaration

Comment: IMO I think it is just bad code, if you declare `_gaq` with the `var` statement, it will shadow *any* other variable named `_gaq`, higher in the scope chain...

Comment: @CMS – Unless you already are in the global scope, which is the case. But even then `var` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Marcel, yeah, the only difference in global code between using `var` or not, is that when you use `var` the identifier is bound to the Variable Object (which is the global object itself for global code) it is marked as non-deleteable. E.g. `var foo = ''; bar = '';` then `delete foo == false;` and `delete bar == true;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it means assign _gaq the value of _gaq unless it is undefined, in which case _gaq will be an empty list.

Comment: Unless `_gaq` it's `undefined`, `null`, `0`, an empty string, `NaN` or `false`...

Answer (score 3):

It's a short way to set _gaq to an empty array if _gaq is undefined.  It's probably used to provide a default value for an argument to a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
_gaq || []
```

Is an expression that will return _gaq if it's a non-false value ( I mean is not 0, nor false, nor '') or an empty array in the other case.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

Always will set [] to _gaq.
I tested it in this way from my firebug console:

```
_gaq = 'crazy value';
(function(){var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
            console.log(_gaq);
 })();
```

Having in mind that _gaq could be a variable defined in the global namespace. But is not the case.

Comment: I think this is the best answer and deserves it to be marked as such (unless mentioned code *is* run in global scope, and I think it is). It clearly elaborates CMS' comment on the question. +10 if I could.