# What does _gaq || [] accomplish for Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking?

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what’s the javascript “var _gaq = _gaq || []; ” for ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538252/whats-the-javascript-var-gaq-gaq-for)

In the asynchronous example of Google Analytic's Ecommerce tracking code, the declaration of the array is:

`var _gaq = _gaq || [];`

I'm trying to understand what they are doing here.  Is this a true `OR` statement?  Is this because of the async treatment of the script tag?

Thanks!

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html#Example

Comment: Same as [what's the javascript "var _gaq = _gaq || \[\]; " for ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538252/whats-the-javascript-var-gaq-gaq-for)

Comment: Thanks.  I searched before posting and didn't find that answer.  Sorry about the repeat.

Answer (score 2):

If _gaq is false/null, it initializes a new array

It's similar to c#'s null coalesce operator `??`

It's a great way to setup defaults on a function

```
function somefunc (a, b, c) {
   a = a || 1;
   b = b || 2;
   c = c || 3;

   return a + b + c;
}

var result = somefunc();
//result = 6;

var result = somefunc(2,4);
//result = 9;
```

Comment: So, this is a true OR statement.  Is this done because of async?

Answer (score 0):

`||` is called the `default operator` in javascript. By:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

They meant: if `_gaq` is not defined let it be an empty array.

But what it really means is:  if `_gaq` is falsey let it be an empty array.

So **beware** as the operator is **not strictly compares** to `undefined`, rather if the value is falsey. So if you got `false`, `null`, `NaN` or `""` (empty string) you may want to avoid this shortcut.

Comment: Thus the dangers of a loosely typed language.