# What does the Google Analytics.js code do?

Tags: google-analytics

Could some explain what does 'www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' do?  I mean how the code works and what are the 2469 lines of code do...

I have seen an explanation of what the code that loads this script do.  It is here:  [Google Analytics Code Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716542/google-analytics-code-explanation).  This is useful, but it only explains how the final script gets loaded, not the inner workings of the actual analytics.js file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a pretty tricky thing to do, but I'm trying my best. I think you should read the [tour] and maybe check out the [faq] whilst you wait for me to waste my life trawling through pages of documentation and decoding this mess of obfuscated code. ;-D

Comment: Hey, I've noticed you've been popping back to Stack Overflow every so often. If you're interested, I've started the analysis up again.

Comment: thanks for this... it is not easy to understand but it helps a lot

Comment: Reading the law in my region, there might be a limit to the parts I can legally reverse-engineer. As far as I can tell, everything I've done so far is allowed, but I might have to stop early.

Comment: Reading the law in my region… there's a law that says I can, and a law that says I can't, so I'm erring on the side of caution for now and deleting the answers. Sorry.

Comment: There's a law in your region that prevents you from renaming variables and formatting code that is downloaded and executed on every visitor's device? O.o